# How to improve performance of RSYNC's delta transfer on receiving host using software only?

Tags: linux, performance, backup, nas, rsync

I'm using RSYNC to backup VMs for Virtual Box from one server to some Synology NAS DS1512+. The important point is that I really want to backup the VM-images itself, NOT individual files within those images. I'm doing that additionally already and is NOT the problem here.

Backing up all those images using `--whole-file` takes ~3 hours. But the NAS uses BTRFS and I would like to use its snapshots features to really only store differences, which doesn't work with `--whole-file`, because the whole file gets transferred and really rewritten. `--inplace` is used already, but doesn't change that concrete aspect, only if new files are created or not. To make efficient use of snapshots, RSYNC really needs to only transfer differences between files.

And that's the problem: When removing `--whole-file` to only transfer those differences, the time necessary to backup the same amount of data increases a lot. I've killed RSYNC after running 10 hours already, because I need it to finish far earlier to not overlap with other backups etc. Looking at the files transferred after those 10 hours, it seemed to have only been half the way anyway. So delta transfer is far too slow for some reason.

I'm somewhat sure that the bottleneck is I/O on the NAS: The server hadn't too much of that and even in theory it shouldn't matter too much if the server reads using `--whole-file` or not. Some of those VMs are hundreds of GiB in size and the server uses ZFS, so those images are not necessarily aligned for optimal sequential reads anyway. It has plenty of free RAM to cache things and the disk are more or less idling when not using `--whole-file`.

Though, especially reads are not too slow on the NAS as well: While there are some drops, it goes up to 50-70 MiB/s for longer periods of time. Writes don't seem too slow as well, but are nowhere as when using `--whole-file`, when it reaches 100+ MiB/s for large periods of time. What's somewhat interesting is the CPU-load, which is pretty high especially when not using `--whole-file` and most likely is necessary because of BTRFS compression. But that compression is needed as well to efficiently use the available space.

[image: htop on the NAS]

My expectation was that especially for reads it shouldn't matter too much if using `--whole-file` or not in my setup. BTRFS and ZFS on the NAS don't necessarily align written files for sequential reads anyway. While I guessed that bursts wouldn't be as high as with `--whole-file`, I expected that delta transfer minimizes the amount of data to write overall and that things would nullify each other therefore. But that doesn't seem to be the case for some reason.

Finally, I'm using the following options:

```
--owner \
--numeric-ids \
--compress-level=0 \
--group \
--perms \
--rsh=rsh \
--devices \
--hard-links \
--inplace \
--whole-file \
--links \
--recursive \
--times \
--delete \
--delete-during \
--delete-excluded \
--rsync-path=[...] \
--specials
```

Is there anything obvious in those options explaining the differences between `--whole-file` and not? Something known to act badly in the latter case? Is there anything that can be improved on the receiving site using RSYNC?

Investing money for more better hardware like SSDs etc. is not an option. Either I find some wrong usage of RSYNC or need to live with `--whole-file` and not having snapshots.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: One possible improvement is to split files, like it's often possible for VM-images, and HOPE(!) that the user of those files doesn't write to all individual ones always. While that doesn't improve DELTA-calculation in itself, it might make RSYNC ignore lots of unchanged files. That would result in less overall reads in the amount of the ignored/unchanged files. https://superuser.com/a/1598665/308859

Answer (score 2):

RSync seems to have this problem with really large files. I sure feel it when transferring VM images. I've seen this problem with files as small as 30GB, but it may manifest with much smaller files.

I'm lucky enough to have a variety of storage hardware to test on. Unfortunately, I can say that SSDs don't help. Whether reading from an SSD on one computer and writing to a slow HDD-based ZFS filesystem on another (over a gigabit link), or between computers with SSDs, the time from starting the RSync to finishing the transfer is no better than just sending the whole-file (`--whole-file`), and usually takes twice as long. I've experimented with different block sizes as well. Smaller (4096 vs 65536) was better, but not by a whole lot.

Since nobody has mentioned using RSync as a daemon on the remote side of the connection, rather than depending on SSH, I'll add that is well worth it. As long as traffic to/from the remote computer doesn't have to traverse an unsafe network, it is an easy way to get wire-speed.

But since you are using BTRFS on your NAS, if you were to also use BTRFS on the source machine you could use BTRFS send and receive to transfer only the changes between snapshots. The first transfer will be painful, worse than with RSync, but subsequent transfers should be very quick. Even better, your snapshots will work as expected, with only the changes consuming storage.

In the past, I've done exactly this, except with ZFS, and it works well. Like with RSync, avoiding SSH where it is safe, say by using `nc`, can be a huge win.

I will probably end up implementing exactly as I describe with BTRFS in the  near future and will report back with my findings.

Comment: I did implement this with BTRFS send and receive. It works very well. I used, `btrfs-sxbackup` to manage making, transferring, and rotating the snapshots. (There are many alternatives to `btrfs-sxbackup`.) The initial backup took hours. Subsequent backups take a couple of minutes, if that.

Answer (score 1):

With `--whole-file`, no reads need to be done on the target side, it can just truncate the file and write it out buffered. It also doesn't need to do any checksumming, you are just transferring the whole file regardless.

Without `--whole-file`, it has to read the whole file on the target side and overwrite the blocks that changed. Reading, especially in a copy-on-write file system like ZFS and BTRFS can be slower than writing.

So I suspect the difference in performance you are seeing comes from greater sequentiality of writes vs. reads. Depending you your ZFS recordsize, you should set the same value with `--block-size`. ZFS recordsize defaults to 128KB, if your version supports large blocks you can set both the ZFS recordsize and rsync block-size to 1MB, that will help reduce fragmentation.

Comment: Are you sure to align with ZFS recordsize instead of that of e.g. the BTRFS target? So you think the sending ZFS is the bottleneck, despite the server has far more resources and seems far more idle than the target? Does the increased block size maps 1:1 to what delta xfer stores as changes and influences size of snapshots this way?

Comment: Details about `--block-size`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111934/174233 Default size: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587783/174233

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought both ZFS and BTRFS were referring to the file systems you could use on the target. I thought you were sending from a regular file system to ZFS. I don't know enough about the inner workings of BTRFS to be able to advise on the details of that.